# Testing useEffect(), Hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-lifecycle-hooks

Hello I'm new testing Hooks, so I'm really lost, tried to find the answer but no result.

So the question is, How can I test `useEffect` from this code?

**Code:**

```
const [ range, setRange ] = useState(DATE_OPTIONS.LAST_30_DAYS)
const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true)

const startLoading = () => setIsLoading(true)
const stopLoading = () => setIsLoading(false)

useEffect(() => {
    startLoading()
    fetchYearlyOptiDrive(range, objectId)
        .then(stopLoading)
        .catch(stopLoading)
}, [range, objectId])
```

And what I wanna test from the code is `LoadingIndicator`, check the props `isLoading`, if it's `true` or `false`.

```
<LoadingIndicator {...{ isLoading }} />
```

**Test:**

```
    test('should return the default value', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<OptiDriveCard {...props} />)
        expect(wrapper.find('LoadingIndicator').props).toBeTruthy()
    })
```

**Error:**

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Any suggestion?

Comment: By the error you are showing, it seems that some component is not right (the error is stating that some component returns `undefined` instead of a string, class or a function). If you check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-lake-g2ev3) you will see that the code runs as expected.

Comment: @mgarcia it was an error of import, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

To check the value passed to a component, you can use the enzyme [prop](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/prop.html) method. In your case:

```
expect(wrapper.find('LoadingIndicator').prop('isLoading')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: now this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`, sorry I'm very noob :(

Comment: That would be your `fetchYearlyOptiDrive` method not returning a promise. You can read about promises [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).